# Exchange restore from week old backup

Tags: exchange-2003, restore, corruption

Our exchange 2k3 database got corrupted and we couldn't revive it, so we're going to restore the last backup, which was unfortunately a week ago :-S

My question is, what happens to the cached emails on users machines for that week? We have outlook and Entourage clients connecting to it, with some imap users via other clients.

As soon as the server comes alive again, will the cached emails on the users machines be deleted? Or synched up to the server? Or will nothing happen?

Thanks :) Just wondering if anyone had experience with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be deleted when the Exchange server comes back online

How many clients do you have? Small enough to export all the cached OSTs to PSTs? Then import them again when the server is back up.

Otherwise, a long shot here, but how far back do your logs go? Maybe you can replay logs and get back that week.

Comment: +1. This happened to me about 10 years ago. We exported the ost files to pst files then imported them (selecting the option to not import duplicates) when the Exchange database was restored.

Comment: +1, so long as you don't have circular logging enabled and the week old backup is your latest you should have all the logs to replay and recover up to time of failure